# JQuery is not getting the value of select object

Tags: php, jquery

I am using two dynamic Objects(One is Select and another is radio button) in a pop-up window. Then call their value to pass on Ajax function. But due to some unknown reason , it does not work. When I Remove radio button it works fine.

PHP code to generate objects:

```
$submit_newform=
'<form method="POST">
<div id="waiting" style="display:none; font-weight:bold">Please wait ...</div><br />
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="3" cellpadding="3">
  <tr><td colspan="4"><h1>Add Component Itinerary</h1></td></tr>
  <tr>`
    <td width="25">Service:</td>

    <td width="25">
    <select name="cmb_service" id="cmb_service" class="dropdown2">
    <option value="">-Select-</option>';
    foreach($services as $k=>$v)
    $submit_newform.= "<option value=".$k.">".$v."</option>";

    $submit_newform.= '</select></td>

    </tr>;


 $submit_newform.='<tr><td><input type="radio" name="package" id="package" value="package"` `class="packagetype" onClick="callservice_provider();">Package</input></td><td><input` `type="radio" name="package" id="package" value="nopackage" class="packagetype"` `onClick="callpackages();">Without Package</input></td></tr></table></form>';
```

and jquery part is as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

        $('input.packagetype').click( function( event ){
            var value = $(this).val();
            if(value =="package")
                {
                    alert("show package");
                }
            else
            {
                var destination = $("#destination").val();
                var service_val = $(cmb_service).val();
                   alert(destination+"+"+service_val);
                $.ajax({
                        type : 'POST',
                        url : '../enquiries/getpricebyajax',
                        dataType : 'json',
                        data: {
                                service : service_val,
                                destno : destination
                        },
                        success : function(data) {
                               alert("success");
                               $('#divserviceprovider').text('');
                               $('#divserviceprovider').append(data.msg);
                               $('#divserviceprovider').show(500);
                               if (data.error === true)
                                    $('#divserviceprovider').show(500);
                        },
                        error : function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                            alert("success");
                                $('#waiting').hide(500);
                                $('#divserviceprovider').removeClass().addClass('error')
                                    .text('There was an error.').show(500);
                                $('#divserviceprovider').show(500);
                        }
                });
                return false;
            }
        });
});
```

Both of objects `select` and `radio button` does not work together. Please suggest me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: $(cmb_service) needs to be $("#cmb_service")

Comment: foreach isn't balanced (i.e. without endforeach) ?

Comment: var value = $("#cmb_service").val(); But this show nothing at all

Comment: What "does not work"? What it should do? Any errors in console?

Comment: You have an error in `$(cmb_service)` . It will be `$("#cmb_service")`. Also if it doesnot solve your problem make a jsfiddle link

Comment: `alert(destination+"+"+service_val);` what is the output?

Comment: Btw, What is the element having id="destination"??

Comment: destination defined earlier. and alert `show destination id+-` e.g. `88+`. It always takes the first value of drop down

Comment: destination defined earlier. and alert `show destination id+-` e.g. `88+`. It always take the first value of drop down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have modified your code a bit hope this helps

```
<html>
    <head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $('input.packagetype').click( function( event ){
            var value = $(this).val();
            if(value =="package")
                {
                    alert("show package");
                }
            else
            {
                var destination = $("#destination").val();
                var service_val = $("#cmb_service").val();
                   alert(destination+"+"+service_val);
                $.ajax({
                        type : 'POST',
                        url : '../enquiries/getpricebyajax',
                        dataType : 'json',
                        data: {
                                service : service_val,
                                destno : destination
                        },
                        success : function(data) {
                               alert("success");
                               $('#divserviceprovider').text('');
                               $('#divserviceprovider').append(data.msg);
                               $('#divserviceprovider').show(500);
                               if (data.error === true)
                                    $('#divserviceprovider').show(500);
                        },
                        error : function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                            alert("success");
                                $('#waiting').hide(500);
                                $('#divserviceprovider').removeClass().addClass('error')
                                    .text('There was an error.').show(500);
                                $('#divserviceprovider').show(500);
                        }
                });
                return false;
            }
        });
});
    </script>

    </head>
    <body>
        <?php

        $services =array('apple','orange','grapes');
$submit_newform=
'<form method="POST">
<div id="waiting" style="display:none; font-weight:bold">Please wait ...</div><br />
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="3" cellpadding="3">
  <tr><td colspan="4"><h1>Add Component Itinerary</h1></td></tr>
  <tr>`
    <td width="25">Service:</td>

    <td width="25">
    <select name="cmb_service" id="cmb_service" class="dropdown2">
    <option value="">-Select-</option>';
    foreach($services as $k=>$v)
    $submit_newform.= "<option value=".$k.">".$v."</option>";

    $submit_newform.= '</select></td>

    </tr>;';


 $submit_newform.='<tr><td><input type="radio" name="package" id="package" value="package" class="packagetype" onClick="callservice_provider();">Package</input></td><td><input type="radio" name="package" id="nopackage" value="nopackage" class="packagetype" onClick="callpackages();">Without Package</input></td></tr></table></form>';
 echo $submit_newform;
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

There are some thing which I like to mention.

1. Do not use same `id` for the radio buttons.
2. I have just seen the alert and it works now.

If you need anything else let me know

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want the selected value of that dropdown?

```
$("#cmb_service option:selected").val();
```

Comment: @AmitJha You're going to have to provide actual errors if you expect any level of help. "Sorry it does not work" might be less helpful than just no reply at all.

Answer (score 0):

your input

```
<input type="radio" name="package" id="package" value="package"` `class="packagetype" onClick="callservice_provider();">Package</input>
```

i dont think input has a closing tags (to my knowledge)

```
<input type="radio" name="package" id="package" value="package" class="packagetype" onClick="callservice_provider();" />Package
```

and you have `onclick` inline function and `click` event in jquery...i wonder...why is that??.. why can't you do both the things in one.. either in your  `callservice_provider()` function or the jquery `click` event..

i think u missed hash here

```
$('#cmb_service').val();
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some flaws in your code

1) You can't give same id for two controls. You have given `id="package"` for both the radio buttons.

2) In Ajax,

```
var service_val = $(cmb_service).val();
```

This line should throw an arror. You can't access the id like this. You must access like

```
var service_val = $("#cmb_service").val();
```

Just check your code once again.

Comment: Why do u have two different functions for Click function?

Answer (score 0):

## See

```
$submit_newform.='<tr><td><input type="radio" name="package" id="package"// same id
                  value="package"` `class="packagetype" 
                  onClick="callservice_provider();">Package</input></td> //</input>
              //--^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^---------^^^^^^^----bad closing
                 <td><input` `type="radio" name="package" id="package" // same id
                 value="nopackage" class="packagetype"
                 onClick="callpackages();">Without Package</input></td>
                </tr></table></form>';
```

If you are clicking a specific radio here then you don't need the inline `onclick` handler:

```
$('input.packagetype').click( function( event ){
```

## and in your else part:

```
var service_val = $(cmb_service).val();
```

## which should be:

```
var service_val = $("#cmb_service").val();
```

---

## So your final code has to be like this:

```
$submit_newform.='<tr><td><input type="radio" name="package" id="package1"
                  value="package"` `class="packagetype"/>Package
                  </td> 
                 <td><input type="radio" name="package" id="package2" 
                 value="nopackage" class="packagetype"/>Without Package
                 </td>
                </tr></table></form>';
```

## jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$(document).on('click', 'input.packagetype', function (event) {
    var value = $(this).val();
    if (value == "package") {
        alert("show package");
    } else {
        var destination = $("#destination").val();
        var service_val = $("#cmb_service").val();
        alert(destination + "+" + service_val);
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '../enquiries/getpricebyajax',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {
                service: service_val,
                destno: destination
            },
            success: function (data) {
                alert("success");
                $('#divserviceprovider').text('');
                $('#divserviceprovider').append(data.msg);
                $('#divserviceprovider').show(500);
                if (data.error === true) $('#divserviceprovider').show(500);
            },
            error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert("success");
                $('#waiting').hide(500);
                $('#divserviceprovider').removeClass().addClass('error')
                    .text('There was an error.').show(500);
                $('#divserviceprovider').show(500);
            }
        });
        return false;
    }
});
});
```